# Absolute difference and probability

Tags: probability, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, integers

Fifty tickets numbered with consecutive integers are in a jar. Two are drawn at random and without replacement. What is the probability that the absolute difference between the two numbers is 10 or less? (The answer should be expressed as a common fraction.)

Well so I was considering both the positive and negative integers, except that then the scale would be too big for me to consider, and then I don't know how to move on. I guess I could try positive integers, but what about negatives? And it doesn't really say whether the numbers are from 1~50; they could be any consecutive numbers like 43~93, I think...

Comment: A counting problem. Consider a $50$ by $50$ matrix, with the rows and columns labeled from $1$ to $50$ (left to right, top to bottom). Then you try to compute the absolute difference of these labels and fill in the corresponding entries. And you will observe a pattern very soon.

Comment: Because you are dealing with the *absolute difference* between the integers, it doesn't matter what range they are in. The problem is the same if they are the integers $\{1,\dotsc,50\}$ or if they are the integers  $\{-156,\dotsc,-107\}$.

Comment: [Here's a picture.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ApEt8.png) You just need to count the colored (x,y) cells in the grid, then take the ratio of this number to the total number of cells that correspond to drawing (x,y) *without replacement*.